# Postgres LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, left-join

I'm having a bit of trouble debugging a SQL query and would really appreciate some help.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.type, p.submission_id, 
  p.title, p.description, p.date, extract('epoch' FROM p.time) AS time, 
  podcasts.image_url, podcasts.title AS podcast_title, 
  COUNT(u1) as upvote_count, u2.id as upvote_id, 
  episodes.mp3_url, episodes.duration, 
  COUNT(c) as comment_count 
FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN upvotes AS u1 ON p.id=u1.post_id AND u1.comment_id=-1 
LEFT JOIN upvotes AS u2 ON p.id=u2.post_id AND u2.user_id=$1 AND u2.comment_id=-1 
LEFT JOIN episodes ON p.submission_id = episodes.id 
LEFT JOIN podcasts ON episodes.podcast_id=podcasts.id 
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.post_id=p.id 
WHERE p.type='podcast' AND p.time IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY(p.id, u2.id, podcasts.image_url, episodes.mp3_url, episodes.duration, podcasts.title);
```

The unexpected behavior comes from the two COUNT statements. I expect upvote_count to be equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upvotes WHERE upvotes.post_id = (individual post id);
```

for each individual post and same for comment count (which I expect to return the total number of comments for each post. However, I am getting strange seemingly random results from these queries for those two fields. Can anybody help me diagnose the problem?

Comment: Unrelated, but: putting parentheses around the columns in the `group by` is useless

Answer (score 2):

`count()` (and all other aggregate functions) ignores null values.

However, `COUNT(c)` references the *complete* row ("record") from the table alias `c` But that is is always **not null** even when all columns of that record are null.

You need to change both `count()` calls and pass a *column* from that table to it, e.g. `count(u1.post_id)` and `count(c.post_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just fixed that. I'm still getting the same strange results though, the counts I'm getting are actually greater than the number of rows in the entire upvotes/comments table

Comment: @user1023465: without more details sample data this is hard to tell - but a join might increase the number of rows in a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. Maybe you want `count(distinct u1.post_id)` instead. The best way to debug this is to run the query **without** the group by and look a the rows that are returned. That will tell you why you get the unexpected numbers.